# Web-Crawler Using PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to develop a **web-crawler** for **Aliexpress** product page details. Everything is possible without ***shipping pop-up*** data. If I call it's returning null value because click event not working.

Image 01:

[image: LINK]

Image 02:

[image: POP-UP]

Like **image 1** when I click the link it shows a pop-up as like **image 2** and I need the pop-up data. It's possible to do with python but I need to do with PHP. If I click the link it will not change the link but it's changing the HTML contents of the page. But I can't grub after change which is possible with python.

What I have done with PYTHON:

```
def extract_product_info(product_url):
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(product_url)
    try:
        print("Got You....")
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('close-layer').click()
    except:
        print("Didn't get You....")

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('shipping-link').click() # Click 
    time.sleep(5)
    content = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    print("Calculating...")
    popup = soup.find('div', {'id': 'j-shipping-dialog'})
    #print(popup)
    return popup
```

Can anyone help me to do with PHP?

Comment: did you find an answer?? i am having a bit of a trouble like that. if u have found a solution can u share.

Comment: yes. I already solved the problem. Please describe your problem, what do you want to know?